# Why can't I find any solution of this three equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$2x+6y-z=10$$
$$3x+2y+2z=1$$
$$5x+4y+3z=4$$
I do not find any solution of this three equations.I know that if two equations or planes are parallel then we do't find any solution.But I can't understand what is the problem here.Are they parallel.and if they are parallel How can I understand that.please  help me.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CramersRule.html

Comment: I was gonna suggest Cramer's Rule, but you beat me to it. Good suggestion.

Comment: Why should there be a solution? The line of intersection of the first two planes could be parallel to the third plane.

Comment: @fazla Rabbi Mashur : I would recommend Gauss-Jordan elimination, avoiding fractions as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$
\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2&6&-1 \\ 3&2&2 \\ 5 & 4 & 3
\end{array}\right)=0$$

So there is either *no* so solution or an infinte amount of solutions.

Now substract the second line from the first line three times, and substract it from the third line twice, tends to

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
-7x-7z &=& 7\\
-x-z &=& 2
\end{array}$$

Can you continue from this point?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%20%2b%206y%20-%20z%20=%2010%20and%203x%20%2b%202y%20%2b%202z%20=%201%20and%205x%20%2b%204y%20%2b%203z%20=%204),

$$z = 2x + 6y - 10, z = -\dfrac{3x}{2} - y + \dfrac{1}{2}, z = -\dfrac{5x}{3} - \dfrac{4y}{3} + \dfrac{4}{3}$$

So there seems to be no solution for this problem.

If we augment 3-by-3 matrix with 3-by-1 matrix and determine reduced row echelon form of 3-by-4 matrix, then we obtain

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$

(Unfortunately, MathJax won't let me set the augmented matrix like this.)

So indeed, there is no solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution. Maybe try your luck with 
$$\tag{(2)+2(1)}7x+14y=21$$
$$\tag{(3)+3(1)}11x+22y=34$$
first.

Comment: @user127001 Right, but only after correcting the mistake André hinted at. (Who works with numbers anyway?)

Answer (score 1):

If your three equations have solutions, they have to satisfy the followings :

$(2)+2\times (1)$ will give you
$$x+2y=3.$$
$(3)+3\times (1)$ will give you
$$x+2y=34/11.$$

However, these does not have any solution (these represent two parallel lines).

So, there is no solution for the given three equations.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\ det\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 6 & -1 \\ 
3 & 2  &  2 \\ 
5 & 4  &  3
\end{pmatrix}= 0$$ while $$rank \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 6 & -1 & 10\\ 
3 & 2  &  2 &   1\\ 
5 & 4  &  3 &   4
\end{pmatrix}=3$$
because $$\begin{vmatrix}
6 & -1  & 10 \\ 
2 &  2 &     1\\ 
4 &  3 &    4
\end{vmatrix} \neq 0$$ so the system has no solutions.

On the other hand reducing the augmented matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 6 & -1 & 10\\ 
3 & 2  &  2 &   1\\ 
5 & 4  &  3 &   4 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\longrightarrow 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 6 & -1 & 10\\ 
0 & -2  &  1 &   -7\\ 
0 & 0  &  0 &   35
\end{pmatrix}
$$. Seeing the last row you realize that can't be possible.